# can anyone help me convert this function into a recursive one?

Tags: python, function, recursion

This code takes a string of letters, numbers, symbols, (pretty much anything) pulls the numbers out concatenates them onto a string and outputs the list of numbers. I'm looking for a way to make this a recursive function instead.

attempted to call the string position after the current one to make it recursive but have no way of telling when to stop (terminating condition) leaving it in an infinite loop.

```
def getdigits(entered):
    print(entered, "maps to")
    nums = ""
    for x in range (0, len(entered)):
        for i in range (0,9):
            if entered[x] == str(i):
                nums += entered[x]
    print(nums)

entered = ("1.234.123[123]")
getdigits(entered)
entered = ("**1.23a-42")
getdigits(entered)
```

expected outputs for the above examples are:

```
1234123123
12342
```

respectively

Comment: Why do you want to use recursion for this?

Comment: Honestly, just attempting to increase my understanding of recursion, it seemed like a relatively easy place to start since i knew the code already.

Comment: A better task for practicing recursion might be something like tree traversal. It will make a lot more sense because the recursion makes the code simpler rather than more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to solve this problem is to initialize a variable empty string(nums = ""):

```
def getdigits(entered, nums = ""):
    if entered:
        if entered[0] in "0123456789":
            nums += entered[0]
        entered = entered[1:]
        # recursive  
        getdigits(entered, nums)
    else:
        # entered is empty string
        print(nums)

entered = ("1.234.123[123]")
getdigits(entered)
entered = ("**1.23a-42")
getdigits(entered)
```

Comment: this is the code i'm not understanding 
"entered = entered[1:]" is this taking the next item from entered and comparing to "0123456789"?

Comment: 1. entered = entered[1:] means each time recursive variable enter getdigits func is  entered[1:] 2. Not comparing to "0123456789", But to see exsit in "0123456789" or not.

Answer (score 1):

While it's possible to make anything recursive, always keep in mind that recursion comes at a cost. That's often maintenance cost because the algorithm confuses the people who have to make it work.

In your case, a good stop condition is "empty string". Cut off characters which you have processed and call yourself recursively with `getdigits(entered[1:])`

Don't forget to remove the loop which you wanted to replace with recursion.

As a mental model, think of this as a way to process items. You can process items by placing them in a line and walking past them (looping / iteration) or by putting them on a stack and picking the first one from the top until the stack is empty (recursion).

Comment: I saw someone in another post using this code, could you possibly explain how it works? the notation within the [ ] is baffling me :/

Comment: @LukePeach [List indexing and slicing](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~spector/extension/python/notes/node29.html). Google is your friend.

Comment: @LukePeach Please don't post code in comments. That said, think about your requirement: You wanted to replace looping with recursion. Which loop did you want to replace?

Comment: I wanted to change the entire function to a recursive one, would this mean changing all loops?

Comment: Yes. But you may want to replace/simplify the second loop with `entered[0].isdigit()`. If you don't, then create a list with the ten digits and also cut away from the top until it's empty.